# JsonConvert throws a 'not a valid integer' exception when deserializing double type variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization

I get an exception when I try to deserialize to an object from a JSON string.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
Input string '106.890907 is not a valid integer. Path 'data[0].loc.coordinates[0]', line 1, position 9413.
```

This is how I deserialize the object:

```
var propertiesObj =
          JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Location>(
              jsonObject);
```

And, this is how my json looks

```
{
    "coordinates":
    [
        106.890907,
        -6.149393
    ],
    "type": "Point"
}
```

Finally, this is how I declare my model class:
**Location.cs**

```
public class Location
{
    public List<double> coordinates { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

I have refer to this question on StackOverFlow but it did not solve my problem, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516642/jsonconvert-throws-a-not-a-valid-integer-exception-when-deserializing-to-a-dou).

Please help. I have been unable to find any solution for this. Thanks.

Comment: is the whole json? because this json is not valid

Comment: No, it is not. I only show portion of it due to confidential information issue. Now I have changed it to the correct json. Thanks for pointing out. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: did below answer worked for you?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

After I reinstalled my Windows 10, this error just mysteriously goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, update JSON:

**From**

```
"loc": {
"coordinates": [
  106.890907,
  -6.149393
],
"type": "Point"
}
```

**To**

```
{
"coordinates": [
  106.890907,
  -6.149393
],
"type": "Point"
}
```

i.e Remove "loc" from Json

Comment: Hi, @Vivek. I show the wrong json in question. I have now changed it to the correct one. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

It's localization problem. You can set your CultureInfo for JsonConvert. 
I think your system accepts double with coma ( , ) not with dot ( . )