# Send dynamic object throught HTTP POST request in c#

Tags: c#, http, post, webapi

I'm trying to send a dynamic object throught and HTTP POst request, but when I Receive that object, it is null.

I cannot USE JObject, cause I have a "virtual" api, and it does not accept JObjects.

I tried to send the type object and dynamic. Both of them do not work. Can some body help me ?

Here's my post request:

```
public static void Post(string uri, object parameter, string serviceName)
        {
            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
            url.Append(uri);
            var client = GetClient(url.ToString(), 300, "application/json");
            var urlParameters = GetUrlParameters(new List<KeyValuePair<string, object>>() { });


            var response = client.PostAsync(
                urlParameters,
                new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter).ToString(),
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json")
                ).Result;

            if (response.StatusCode != System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
                throw new Exception($"{serviceName}: {response.StatusCode}");
        }
```

Here is where i Receive that post:

Interce for method:

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
           UriTemplate = "Teste")]
        void Teste(object requestData);
```

Method implemented in class( this is acctually where i get the data):

```
public void Teste(object requestData)
        {
            var teste = requestData;
            var t1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData); // this returns {}; (empty)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you tweak your POST a bit to troubleshoot the issue a bit more?  Something like the following? (not compiled)

```
var rawJson = await client.PostAsync(
                urlParameters,
                new StringContent(
                    JsonConvert.SerializeObject(parameter).ToString(),
                    Encoding.UTF8,
                    "application/json")
                ).Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

var mappedObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(rawJson,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            // convert this to your logger
            LogHelper.Instance.Warning(2000, string.Format("Failed object mapping: {0}\n{1}",
                args.ErrorContext.Error, rawJson));
            args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
        },
        // set culture to mitigate mapping issues related to dates/numbers
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529198
        Culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
    });
```